# Bootstrap slider off-canvas is not working perfectly in mobile chrome browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, slider

i am using bootstrap **v3.2.0**, creating a theme. Bootstrap was working fine in system browser but as it was almost done, in testing mode i came to know that slider is not working fine on the real devices.
my menu is on left and it has **toggle** button to show the left menu in small screen, but on mobile or tabs it appears and pushes the body to right but the body does not slide it-self which results its size get small and adjust in the screen. it should slide to right.
my HTML is

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="MainHeader">


    <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="logo left">
        ABC Company
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

</div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav header-float">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->


    </div>
    <!-- /Header -->

    <div class="" style="">

        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="MainMenu" role="navigation" style="margin-right: -15px;">

                <div class="" id="Leftmenu">
    <ul id="Leftmenu">
 <li class="active">home</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>

</ul>
</div>
            </div>

                <div id="MainGrid" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="pull-left visible-xs">
                            <button type="button" class="panel-button btn-    xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                                    Togglenav
                                </button>
                           </p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" id="MainContents">
                            Body...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div><!--/row-->
```

css and js files are not attached,Bootstrap version is mentioned above.

Comment: Try upgrading Bootstrap to the latest version.